# .htaccess mod_rewrite rules conflicting

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rules:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt)$


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(Account|Logout|Password|Tags) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?city=$1 [QSA,L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Account [NC]
    RewriteRule ^Account /members/account.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Logout [NC]
    RewriteRule ^Logout /members/logout.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Password [NC]
    RewriteRule ^Password /members/password.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Tags [NC]
    RewriteRule ^Tags /members/tags.php [NC,L]
```

I'm trying to add another condition that so that it loads as

```
  domain.com/$city/$provider/$name
```

this is the rule:

```
  RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /listing.php?city=$1&provider=$2&urlname=$3 [L]
```

My issue is that this rule conflicts with the rule for my index file which loads as domain.com/$city.

I'd greatly appreciate any and all suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the meaning of `loads as`? Are you talking about a client-visible redirect? I.e. I type in `http://example.com/foo` but actually when the page loads `http://example.foo/bar` is in the address bar? Is that "foo 'loads as' bar"?

Comment: no, just load content as is, so if someone goes to mysite.com/new-york it will load it mysite.com/index.php?city=new-york,  but if someone goes to mysite.com/new-york/business_name/tag_of_listing, it will load as mysite.com/listing.php?city=new-york&provider=business_name&name=tag_of_listing.

Comment: I wont be changing the header location at all, this is purely for incoming traffic to get the right db results.

Comment: I see. You want to do pattern matching on up to three levels of city/business/tag and rewrite these into URL query parameters, which is what your rule is trying to do.

Comment: You will need separate rules. First try to match the case when you have all three components: city, provider, name.   Then try to match the case when there is only city and provider, and finally the case when there is only city. Also, do you have a list of cities instead of matching anything? At least restricting it to alphabetic characters or something.

Comment: there are only 3 scenarios for how inbound traffic should be handled, 1st is, domain.com/city, that currently works, 2nd is, domain.com/$city/$provider/$name, and 3rd is domain.com/listing, but i'm not concerned with the 3rd as of yet.  I currently have it as a separate rule and it works if i append it with ^listing, however, I dont want to keep that naming scheme.  I couldn't think of the rules or how to properly put them all together.  .htaccess and regex is a whole new beast to me.

Comment: About that conflict, maybe you just need a `RewriteCond` to check for a match on the index file so it is not treated as a city, even if it looks like one.

Comment: is it possible to write it so that if its 1 variable, then its index.php/?city, if its 3, then its listings.php/$1/$2/$3 without prepending it with additional tags?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it with a single `RewriteRule` because the logic has to conditionally omit query parameters when the corresponding URL components are missing.  Have a rule for the city/provider/name and another one for the city (but with a `RewriteCond` checking that city isn't matching some of your other one-component URLs).

Comment: Can the 2nd condition be the number of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with any of your rules.  Its just that the first covers the last in terms of what it will accept.  The easiest way to avoid this problem is to move the more restrictive rule above of the more general.  I.e. in this case put the Listing rule immediately before the index.php rule.

## Addendum

Oops, The ->listing.php followed by the ->indexp.php rules will still loop because rule1 fires on the first pass and then rule2 on the second, since the query string is stripped for purposes of regexp matching in a rule; and "`listing.php` matches `^([^/]*)$`.

You should only match `^([^/]*)$` in the case where the pattern doesn't match an existing file.  The way to prevent this is to put a

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

before the index.php rule.

Comment: I tried putting the broader rule above the one for my index, but it just went into an loop split uri=/index.php?city=index.php -> uri=/index.php, args=city=index.php&city=index.php&city=index.php&city=index.php&city=index.php&city=index.php&city=index.php&city=index.php&city=index.php&city=index.php&city=new-york.

Comment: @Mike, sorry I missed an interlock.  See my addendum.